# Why was my suggested edit rejected when I added code posted by the author in comments?

Tags: discussion, edits, suggested-edits, rejected-edits

The suggested edit: https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/13006182

Link to the question: [Read the data from the CSV File and it should automatically generate the EMAIL_ID to the JSP Page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38349727)

I want to know why shouldn't edit the question like this. It fairly improves the question.

Glorfindel's Edit:

[image]

My Edit:

[image]

Comment: Most likely the reviewers didn't notice the revision note.

Comment: I'm guessing what @Servy said. However, *edited code as provided in comments* is perhaps a little ambiguous (perhaps "edited code" sets of alarm bells and "provided in comments" doesn't mention by whom) - maybe: *adding code that OP mistakenly provided in comments instead of editing their question* or similar would be much harder to misinterpret as to the intent of the edit.

Comment: OP provided wrong code too, he was using incomplete `javascript` function and incomplete `try-catch` block from Java. However, i don't think it matters. In any way, my intent was to make the question better. Also, before edit, the question is still incomplete

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I agree with you, the reviewers should have approved your edit. You indicated your action in the edit summary, but we all know reviewers aren't always paying attention. They just see a wall of code / data being added to the question, seemingly out of nowhere (note that when reviewing suggested edits, you **cannot** see the comments on the post.)

The OP is to blame, because they could easily edit their code / data into their own question. I informed them about this and fixed the post in the meantime.

Comment: yes, for sure. Shouldn't the reviewers must have more reputation then? OP is a new user(1 rep). Or at least, they should be able to see Edit Comments, any minor edit can make a post perfect or worse. Reviewers must be experienced.

Comment: @rupinderjeet47 Minus the OP of the post, who didn't review in this case, reviewers must have 2k rep. And they _can_ see the edit summary you entered, but that doesn't mean 1) that they paid attention to it or 2) that they realized it was code from the OP. (As mentioned by Servy and Jon in the comments above.)

Comment: I thought the OP is a new user, he isn't experienced about SO. It was not his blame. I wouldn't downvote his question. Instead, we should have something like Suggested Edit Response Quality, where other users be able to supervise if the edit was correct or not. This will add another layout to make Edits better. Also, @kendra said **they can see edit summery**. Can someone confirm me?

Comment: @rupinderjeet47 the OP could at least have read the [tour], where it is stated (emphasis mine) *Focus on questions about an actual problem you have faced. **Include details about what you have tried and exactly what you are trying to do.***

Comment: @rupinderjeet47 yes, as a reviewer you do see the edit summary. The review queue is *exactly* what you describe as 'Suggested Edit Response Quality'.

Answer (score 8):

You forgot to fix all of the other glaringly obvious problems with the question when you edited.

When an edit only makes an improvement that I could redo very quick and easily, and there are other glaring issues, then I will reject and edit the suggestion.

In this case, the edit would be best done directly from the question. Unfortunately, the UI doesn't make this very easy/convenient for reviewers to do; you would have to leave the queue, go to the question, copy the comments, click "edit (1)", click "reject and edit", then  paste the code, and fix all the other errors. This is likely why the edit was rejected, yet none of them fixed the post.

Let me point out the errors you missed:

> I'am having a two textboxs namely, LVPL_name and Email_ID. **<This entire sentence needs to be rewritten.>**
>
> If I select any name from the dropdown list of the LVPL_name **<needs comma here>** it should automatically generate the respective email-id from the CSV File and display **<it>** in the JSP Page.
>
> This is my sample Excel Sheet **<Where?>**
>
> Edit: **<No need to add "Edit">**
>
> My sample code:
>
> ```
> try { 
>     String fileName = "LVPL_names.csv";
>     CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(fileName ));
>     String[] rows = new CSVReader(reader).readEmail_ID();
>     if (x == Aarthi) { 
>         System.out.println("Selected LVPL_name"+name.index of (Email_ID));
>     } else { 
>         System.out.println("Enter the Email_ID"); 
>     } 
> } catch(){
> }
> ```
>
> And my My Excel sheet is:
>
> ```
> LVPL_name   Email ID 
> -----------------------
> aaaaa1      aaaaa1@sap.com 
> aaaaa2      aaaaa2@sap.com 
> aaaaa3      aaaaa3@sap.com 
> aaaaa4      aaaaa4@sap.com 
> aaaaa5      aaaaa5@sap.com
> ```
>
> I think something is wrong in my code can any one help me. **<This is fluff and should be removed...or just not added really>**

---

The other thing I noticed, after coming back to this, is how ambiguous your edit summary was:

> edited code as provided in comments

Whose code? Did someone provide an answer in the comments again? The edit review queue is a crazy place, but that type of edit wouldn't be the craziest thing I saw there.

Remember, we can't see the context while reviewing. (It's annoying, actually.)

Comment: There is a Improve button for that. My edit might not uave been correct grammatically. Does this mean I shouldn't even improve them because I didnt make it high-notch-top-quality-butter-slice edit. Oh please, and my edit was rejected. Currently, post is edited by @Glorfindel. If my remove that fluff, people like you ask 'what is the problem you facing?' 'You should mention the problem'

Comment: @rupinderjeet47 "I think something is wrong with my code" does not describe the problem, so even if it remains in the question, people might have to ask those questions. The fluff is completely useless and should be removed.

Comment: edited my question, now you can compare @glorfindel and my edit. There's fluff in both of them :D He literally copied my edit and submitted it, it got accepted. Justify This. :D Try to re-edit the question, and remove fluff, you will get rejected :D and the 'Where?' thing was asked in question-comments already.

Comment: @rupinderjeet47 when you have >2k reputation, your edit will be approved automatically - it doesn't go in the review queue anymore.

Comment: If you can't be bothered to do the job right, at least don't get in the way of people that are making *some* significant, non-trivial improvements. "Reject" is not one of the correct options here. (R&E? Maybe. IE? Sure. Approve? Maybe. Skip? Obviously yes.)

Comment: @rupinderjeet47 That's just my style of review (I'm not blindly clicking buttons like a robo-reviewer). If I want to put in the work to redo and expand on an edit, that is well within my right. On Stack Overflow, I have gained the 2k rep required to review and my edits need no review (and thus I have more freedom editing). I still occasionally suggest edits on other sites, where I am sure to correct EVERYTHING I see is wrong on the post.

Comment: If an edit improves a post, but doesn't improve everything, then you should **not** reject, you should **Improve** instead.

Answer (score 5):

I think I was actually the one who rejected it. The main reason was that it added a large body of code that did not seem to originate from the original poster. The edit summary "edited code as provided in comments" did not convey to me that the code was given by the OP in the comments.

Another reason was that the line "This is my sample Excel Sheet" still did not introduce an excel sheet.

Comment: Edits that insert code are a tricky case. Note that you did exactly the same thing when _you_ edited my https://stackoverflow.com/a/32575174/341994 — you tried to insert, as if it came from me, code that wasn't mine and was incorrect. It would have been more proper just to point out to me, in a comment, that my code was outdated; I would then have updated it (and have now done so, so thank you anyway).

Comment: @matt Sorry for that. But note that the code I added was not incorrect (it was even what XCode suggested the preferred way of doing it is). But the alternative that you edited now works as well, so that is fine.

Comment: It was incorrect. The Xcode fix-it reference to the `NSCoder.string` thing is a bug. If you disagree, you supply your own answer: you don't make me appear to say something I would not say. (BTW thanks for being willing to discuss this! I don't mean to sound harsh, just pointing out that code edits can be controversial and it's perfectly reasonable to find them so, as in this thread.)

Comment: Making an edit to an answer is always a suggestion, the original author can always reject the edit. So I don't really see a problem with doing that instead of making the same suggestion in comments.The end goal of StackOverflow is to get good questions and answers through community effort, not necessarily to keep the original author happy. In our specific case, your own edit now shows an alternative that also works, so I do not see a reason to discuss this further.