# How was my edit defacing or destructive?

Tags: support, edits, suggested-edits, rejected-edits, reject-reasons

The two reviewers of https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/22388699 agreed that

> This edit defaces the post in order to promote a product or service, or is deliberately destructive.

I'm a bit baffled. I replaced an explanation of a detail with the full code (which includes the detail) from [the post author's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55025731/in-dyalog-apl-how-do-i-turn-off-auto-scaling-in-a-form#comment96805296_55025731), and removed some necessary text. I also added very relevant tags:

[winforms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/winforms) because the post is about Dyalog APL's interface to WinForms

[scale](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/scale) because the question is about (unwanted) scaling of one GUI element in relation to another

[default-value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/default-value) because the user clearly wanted a behaviour that differs from the default behaviour.

As I'm fairly inexperienced on SO, please explain to me why my edit defaced the post with promotion of a product or service, or was deliberately destructive.

Comment: Significant Code changes are generally rejected. If you were adding from OP's comment, you could have mentioned it in the suggest edit comment

Comment: Slightly related to: [Why was my suggested edit rejected when I added code posted by the author in comments?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/327926/why-was-my-suggested-edit-rejected-when-i-added-code-posted-by-the-author-in-com)

Comment: Well, "insert code [..]" is a rather unclear description for an edit when you wanted to say "add OPs code from a comment they wrote under the question".

Comment: Also, by adding tags like _scale_ and _default-value_ you're at least risking me rejecting it for that. Those tags are overly broad, and not very descriptive of the question. They add nothing to the question in my opinion

Comment: I dont think either of those duplocates do it justice because the OP here did not clearly explain what they were doing in the edit comment, as opposed to both of the duplicates where such an explanation was used. The answer here is: ... Because you didn't usd the edit comment to properly explain your edit."

Comment: @TinyGiant Sounds like an answer to me.

Comment: Note that while Tiny seems like a sane advice, nothing guarantees that reviewers would read a finely written edit comment, see https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/199584/213575 and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/315855/792066

Comment: @Braiam Right. I guess sub 2000 rep users just shouldn't attempt at editing then.

Comment: Actually, I consider the opposite approach. Non-reviewers shouldn't review at all.

Comment: @Braiam That would require a change in behaviour of others. I'm attempting to change my own behaviour first.

Comment: That's exactly what *I* don't want. Your behavior is good, and should be promoted and fostered. The reviewers behavior is bad and should be discouraged.

Comment: Reviewers can not see the comments so it is super important to use an appropriate edit summary.

Comment: @PeterMortensen Sounds like a fault in the UI then.

Comment: @Adám not really - how would the UI show a 30 comment long chain with limited screen real estate.  And Edit Reviewers shouldn't need to read through a long comment chain to understand why an edit was needed.  That is what the edit summary is for - to provide a the editor a way to communicate the reason/need/importance to the reviewers, and to serve also as a general note in the review history about why the edit was needed

Comment: `'F' ⎕WC 'Form' 'Drawing Lines' ('Size' 25 50) ('Coord' 'Pixel') ⋄ 'F.Line' ⎕WC 'Poly' ((10 90)(5 60))` looks almost exactly like gibberish code edits in an audit. If this is some kind of special dsl (with Unicode nonsense in it) I feel bad for folks who edit in the tag, because there's going to be a lot of false negative reviews.

Comment: In fact, it looks like this might be the case. I'd get management involved in tracking rejected edits in related tags and, if it is found to be a problem, some sort of remediation be considered.

Comment: I have retroactively approved this edit, because it was a helpful edit and the rejection was invalid. The problems were two-fold: (1) your edit comment was inadequate, as it did not explain the origin of this code you were adding, and (2) as Will said, the code you added was indistinguishable from gibberish. That is, of course, a problem with Dyalog, but suggested edits are reviewed by the entire community, not just tag/subject matter experts.